# update of a subdocument's field in an array of documents in MongoDB using the positional operator with Mango

Tags: mongodb, perl

I have a bunch of documents each containing an array similar to the following:

```
{
  _id: 4,
  grades: [
     { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
     { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 }
  ]
}
```

and I wish to update the `std` field of the subdocument that has the corresponding `grade=85`.
I'm using the [Mango driver](https://metacpan.org/release/ODC/Mango-1.18/) and its `update` method complains or silently ignores the update if I try to use the [positional ($) operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) in statements like the following:

```
my $result = $self->collection->update({_id => 4, grades => {grade => 85}}, {'$set' => {'grades.$.std' => 6, 'grades.$.new_field' => 'test'}});
```

and

```
my $result = $self->collection->update($oid, {grades => {grade => 85}}, {'$set' => {'grades.$.std' => 6}});
```

and can't get the subdocument updated properly. The Mango `update` method works when not specifying a positional operator though. Also, `find_and_modify` was not giving me a better outcome.

When trying to use the `$elemMatch` operator (although not needed, I think, since I have only one query) I get something along the line of `Write error at index 0: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$elemMatch' in 'grades.$elemMatch' is not valid for storage. at ...`

How can I go about doing this with Mango, please?

If Mango's `update` method dose not support this, is it supported with the [MongoDB official Perl driver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MongoDB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating while making use of the [positional ($) operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) is supported in the [MongoDB official Perl driver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MongoDB).

The following would updates a field in the subdocument of an array embedded in a specific document:

```
my $oid = MongoDB::OID->new("...");
$self->collection->update(
  {_id => $oid, 'grades.grade' => 85},
  {'$set' => {'grade.$.new_field' => 'test'}}
);
```